# Como trabalhar com varios parametros em c#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde. Preciso de uma ajuda, tenho uma combobox com 3 opções, e preciso passar qualquer uma das trez opções como parâmetro de uma procedure no sql para uma consulta, mas como sou novo em c# nunca passei mais de um parâmetro para uma consulta no sql server, agora estou com esta dificuldade, que preciso passar o parâmetro escolhido no combobox, e ou CHEKLIST ou FORNECEDOR ou CNPJ. A procedure já esta funcionando no sql.

Segue minha tela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue meu código

```
private void btn_consultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand xml = new SqlCommand("usp_consultachkrecebimento", conexaoUSUARIOS(true));
        xml.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHEKLIST", this.txt_consultar.Text);
        xml.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORNECEDOR", this.txt_consultar.Text);
        xml.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNPJ", this.txt_consultar.Text);
        xml.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        xml.ExecuteNonQuery();

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(xml);
            DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
            dados.Fill(dtLista);

            dgw_consultaxml.DataSource = dtLista;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a retornar por favor verifique como o Administrador do sistema");
            return;
        }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue a procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_consultachkrecebimento]

     @CHEKLIST    AS VARCHAR(10)
    ,@FORNECEDOR  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@CNPJ        AS VARCHAR(20)

    AS
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT 
    R.ID_CKCLIST,
    R.CHV_NFE,
    R.N_FONEC,
    R.N_NOTA,
    R.N_CNPJ,
    R.N_IE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(R.DT_RECEBIM AS DATE), 103) AS RECEBIMENTO
    FROM tbl_chkrecebimento AS R
    WHERE (@CHEKLIST IS NULL      OR ID_CKCLIST = @CHEKLIST)
    AND   (@FORNECEDOR IS NULL    OR N_FONEC LIKE '%' + @FORNECEDOR + '%')
    AND   (@CNPJ IS NULL          OR N_CNPJ = @CNPJ)
END
```

Comment: você pretende realizar uma consulta? por exemplo um select onde o cnpj seja igual ao do campo digitado, correto?

Comment: Isso correto.Mas preciso saber qual campo estou passando porque se eu passar o CNPJ o campo FORNECEDOR e CHEKLIST recebe null

Comment: tem q ter os  3 parametros sempre ? mas se não for a opção escolhida, os outros tem que passar null ? ->  `xml.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHEKLIST", combo.SelectedIndex == 0 ?  this.txt_consultar.Text : null);`

Comment: Rovann sua opção esta passando o mesmo valor nos tres parametros, por exemplo se eu passo o parametro CHEKLIST = 000003, O parametro FORNECEDOR esta pegando 000003 tambem e não null.

Comment: Inclua a sua procedure na pergunta.

Comment: Ja inclui a procedure

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Veja a edição da minha resposta

Comment: Obrigado a todos, alterei a procedure como o Leandro me indicou ai deu certinho a consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade depende de como está a sua procedure, mas no cenário atual com os dados fornecidos, você poderia fazer uma condição para determinar qual parâmetro será enviado de acordo com a seleção do seu `DropDownList`, que como você não apresenta seu id vou chamá-lo de `ddl_Filtro`

```
private void btn_consultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand xml = new SqlCommand("usp_consultachkrecebimento", conexaoUSUARIOS(true));

    switch(this.ddl_Filtro.SelectedValue){
        case "CHEKLIST" :
            xml.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHEKLIST", this.txt_consultar.Text);
            break;
        case "FORNECEDOR" :
            xml.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORNECEDOR", this.txt_consultar.Text);
            break;
        case "CNPJ":
            xml.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNPJ", this.txt_consultar.Text);
            break;
    }
    xml.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    xml.ExecuteNonQuery();

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(xml);
        DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
        dados.Fill(dtLista);

        dgw_consultaxml.DataSource = dtLista;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a retornar por favor verifique como o Administrador do sistema");
        return;
    }
}
```

Já na sua procedure adicione valores padrões na declaração dos parâmetros

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_consultachkrecebimento]

     @CHEKLIST    AS VARCHAR(10) = NULL
    ,@FORNECEDOR  AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,@CNPJ        AS VARCHAR(20) = NULL

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT 
    R.ID_CKCLIST,
    R.CHV_NFE,
    R.N_FONEC,
    R.N_NOTA,
    R.N_CNPJ,
    R.N_IE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(R.DT_RECEBIM AS DATE), 103) AS RECEBIMENTO
    FROM tbl_chkrecebimento AS R
    WHERE (@CHEKLIST IS NULL      OR ID_CKCLIST = @CHEKLIST)
    AND   (@FORNECEDOR IS NULL    OR N_FONEC LIKE '%' + @FORNECEDOR + '%')
    AND   (@CNPJ IS NULL          OR N_CNPJ = @CNPJ)
END
```

Comment: Leandro me tira uma duvida, o ddl_Filtro, este e oi meu combobox ou não. porque estou com erro nesse valor, meu programa não acha o ddl_Filtro.

Comment: Como eu expliquei, foi o nome que eu dei de exemplo, você substitui pelo deu combobox, porque não dá pra advinhar qual nome você deu para ele :P

Comment: Mas o erro que você adicionou à pergunta, indica que você ainda vai precisar fazer mais alterações para ter o mínimo de funcionalidade.

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro alterei a procedure como vc indicou e deu certo. Vlw